# What soft drinks mix well with alcohol to make a great drink?

Tags: taste, recommendations, drink

What [soft drinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_drink) mix well with alcohol to make a great, yet unique tasting drink?

We have all heard of ***rum and coke*** which is known as a [Cuba Libre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuba_Libre). I would like to try some other [soft drinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_soft_drinks_by_country#Morocco) with alcohol mixes that could be in someway less commonly known to the average person, like rum and coke. I would appreciate any recommendation possible and the reasons why the recommendation makes a great yet unique tasting drink.

Bottoms Up!

Comment: I'd think vodka would pair well with the fruitier sodas. But really, though, if you need to pollute liquor with a soft drink, rye/ginger is the way to go ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite Hi Ball of all Time is Vernor's(an obscure, potent ginger all type soda) and whiskey.  Two powerful flavors that manage to keep their potency while still blending very well.

*As a general rule for all of these Using a 12oz glass, I would pour 1.5 oz of liquor with 4.5oz soda directly over ice- stir gently.  Drink with a full sized straw.  Garnish with lime, orange, cherry, or lemon as appropriate.* (The straw may seem unimportant, but in fact it creates a different experience than a sip straw or no straw)

If you're into sweet things I recommend Tuaca and Cream Soda (Jones' is my favorite for this).  Tuaca is 80 proof and is sort of a Vanilla and Orange Liquor with butterscotch after notes.  It's sweetness blends well into soda(also Vernor's as above, coke, orange soda, etc..) and very efficiently hides the alcohol.

**Some traditional Hi-Balls:**

Vodka with Soda Water and Lime: Descriptive words: Strong, simple, skinny, diet, crisp

Spiced Rum and Coke- Quite different from a cuba libre.  Descriptive words: Sweet, easy, deceptive, spiced, flavorful

Vodka and Tonic and Lime: Descriptive words: Strong, simple, skinny, diet, potent, blunt, Quinine

Jack Daniels and Ginger: Descriptive words: Sweet, Bright, Easy, Traditional

Scotch and Soda (The original Hi-Ball): Descriptive words: Traditional, potent, slow-sipping

**Some non-traditional quick combos:**

Cake Vodka and Coke: Descriptive words: Soda Shop, Sweet, Vanilla Coke, Rich

Whipped Cream Vodka and Orange Soda: Descriptive words: dessert, old-fashioned, soda shop, masked alcohol, deceptively strong

Pear or Apple Vodka and Sparkling Apple Juice:  Descriptive words: Apple Pie, Crisp, Sweet, Refreshing

**Skinny Bitch** - Vodka and Diet Coke: Descriptive words: Diet, skinny, easy

**Dirty Shirley** - Vodka (or cherry vodka) Ginger Ale (or Sprite) and grenadine(3/4 oz):  Descriptive words: Sweet, fun, masked alcohol, deceptively strong, bubbly

**Double O-7** - Orange Vodka/ lemon vodka orange slice or splash of OJ mixed with 7/up sprite :  Descriptive words: Crisp, lively, effervescent, citrus, refreshing, bubbly

**Swamp Juice** (Named for color of beverage) - Mountain Dew and Captain Spiced Rum: Descriptive words: Energizing, sharp, citrus

Comment: Quite an informative answer, zenijos10.

Answer (score 2):

7 & 7 is popular

Seven Up and Seagrams 7 Crown

Comment: Would ruin the taste of the...Seagrams, if you ask me,

Answer (score 2):

If you want something sweet you can try

amaretto and coke ([some more detailed information)](http://cocktails.lovetoknow.com/amaretto-coke)
for an even sweeter experience you can even go for a mix with Dr pepper

It has a slimier taste to a bakewell tart so it is recommended if you like sweet things

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting one is [Ciroc Peach](https://www.ciroc.com/vodkas/peach) with 7-Up/Sprite. Tastes like fuzzy peach juice. You can mix 7-Up/Sprite with any of the other flavors of Cioc(or any flavored vodka if we generalize) but I find Peach the best for my personal tastes.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Red Wine and Coke**. And do not forget the ice... It is great one hot days.

> Turns out this is quite a hit in most of Europe already. Who would have thought that red wine and coke would go this well together? It is coke with a grape twist and its taste killer. - [Red Wine and Coke](http://ca.askmen.com/recess/recommended/best-soda-and-alcohol-combinations-4.html)